# Execute SQL task with T-SQL sp or Executing the Sp from SSMS ,which one is performance wise better?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a T-sql stored procedure, which inserts millions of records to a SQL Server table. I have 2 options to execute this Stored Procedure

1. Execute the SSIS "Execute SQL task" with  SP
2. Execute the Sp in SSMS

Which one will execute faster, and provide better performance?

(via comment)
The  SP loads a CSV file into SQl 2000 database. Planning to use SSIS 2005 to migrate csv to sql 2000 table, so which method would be better

Comment: so, for (1) you will have the SP code in a script or are you using EXEC SP? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also invoke your stored procedure using a .NET library, calling it from the command line (OSQL, SQLCMD, etc), starting it in a SQL Agent job but the calling program doesn't matter in the slightest.

Ultimately, the SQL Server Database Engine will receive the request that you'd like to run a stored procedure and for the same parameters, it's going to use the same query plan regardless of the caller.

If you are observing differences, check out Erland's article: [Slow in the application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

So, your real question seems to be about loading a CSV. Your stored procedure approach should still give you the same performance regardless of how it's started. As long as you have a fixed CSV file (you aren't trying to write a generic import-anything), you might get better performance by using an actual `Data Flow Task`. It'd certainly be easier to troubleshoot.

And for some unasked for advice, if you're just now starting to get out of SQL Server 2000, skip 2005 and head for SQL Server 2008 R2. [SQL Server end of life](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=SQL&wa=wsignin1.0) has already occurred for 2000. 2005 expires in 2016. The change in licensing costs shouldn't be bad migrating from 2000 to 2008 R2 shouldn't be bad. 2012 though, that's going to cost a pretty penny. Pity, as it's a beauty.

Comment: 2012 only really costs more if you have processors with more than 4 cores. (Or if you were using Enterprise + CAL which is no longer an option.)

Answer (score 2):

There MIGHT be the difference if BIDS installed on the Server is 32 bit and the Server itself is 64 bit.

Running from a SSIS package then will use 32 bit - which also sets the limits for max RAM it can use.

At the same time, when you run the same package as a Server Job, it's going to use all the memory available for 64bit. This is basically true for data flows, but MIGHT also make difference for SQL Tasks.

Comment: tHE SP LOADS A CSV FILE into SQl 2000 database.Planning to use ssis 2005 to migrate csv to sql 2000 table,so which method would be better

Comment: I'd use a server job. You can easily check on progress, but no need to keep the BIDS/SSMS opened